# How can filter the record with two time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, time, between

i have table with time field and i have two parameter time. select the record not the time between those times

ex

```
 p1 = 14:00:00 , p1 = 21:00:00
```

The sample table is

```
 ------------------------
| id | time     | status|
 ------------------------
| 1  | 12:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 2  | 10:56:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 3  | 09:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 4  | 16:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 5  | 02:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 6  | 20:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
```

And i need to select that record except those id 4,6

output like

```
------------------------
| id | time     | status|
 ------------------------
| 1  | 12:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 2  | 10:56:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 3  | 09:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
| 5  | 02:00:00 | 1     |
 ------------------------
```

how can make the mysql for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE time NOT BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '21:00:00'
```